# What R packages are available for exact survival analysis of rare events?

Tags: r, survival

I am working with a dataset containing rare events (around 5%) and I am interested in performing exact survival analysis using R. However, I have noticed that some of the packages I previously used for this purpose are no longer available.

Can anyone recommend any R packages that are currently available for performing exact survival analysis on datasets with rare events?

Thank you in advance for any advice or recommendations!

Comment: What packages did you use in the past?  Which one are you currently using, is any?

Comment: This question will likely yield a lot of opinion-based answers and since it is about programming, it is likely better served on Stack Overflow instead.